# how to draw an arrow with KDE plasma's mouse tracker?

Tags: kde-plasma-workspace

I did this by accident
[image]
it is a straight line drawn by the computer, not free-handed, and there's a an arrow tip. I think I have pressed Meta+Shift+Ctrl or alt, I don't quite remember. The thing is sometimes it just draws the tip, sometimes it draws the entire arrow... Anybody got this figured out ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can "draw" an arrow on KDE/KWin by pressing Meta+Ctrl+Shift twice. The first press is at the arrow head. The second at the tail/end.

Additionally:

- To clear all *mouse marks*: Meta+Shift+F11
- To free draw: hold Meta+Shift while moving the mouse.

Comment: It takes a little practice but I eventually mastered the Art. Thanks @CubitusRadius

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Kde5 plasma

Comment: @Herrgott I forgot to mention you need to enable the Mouse Mark desktop effect in the kde control center > system settings > desktop effects > all effects. See https://i.imgur.com/uRYzgdj.png

Comment: This doesn't really work; it registers a "point" after pressing Meta+Ctrl+Shift *and* moving a mouse. It's all but impossible to move a mouse by exactly 1 pixel, resulting in the image very much like the one shown in the question.